# Append() not working inside if statement which is inside .each loop jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to append some text after the 4th element inside ul li so I am using the append function for it. The problem is if the statement not working inside .each function and it is appending before every li element.

Here is HTML markup

```
<ul class="gallery">
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$('.gallery li').each(function( index ) {
        var count = 3;
        if( index == count){
            $( ".gallery li a" ).append('<span>Learn More</span>');
        }
    });
```

What is the problem is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you just use `$('.gallery li:eq(3) a').append(...)`?

Comment: It's obvious what you wanted to do. What's less obvioius is why you thought this would do it? What part of `$(".gallery li a")` says that it should only append to the current item in the loop?

Comment: I don't mean to single you out. There are hundreds of questions like this, it seems to be a common expectation that the selector will only apply within the context of the current loop element.

Comment: I am new to jquery I didn't know well about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to target the fourth element, then you don't need a loop. You can select it directly using `:eq()`. Note that the index is zero-based, so the fourth element is index `3`. Try this:

```js
$('.gallery li:eq(3) a').append(' <span>Learn More</span>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery">
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably only want to append to the list item you're currently iterating on:

```js
$('.gallery li').each(function(index) {
  var count = 3;

  if (index == count) {
    $(this).find('a').append('<span> Learn More</span>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="gallery">
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Some Text</a></li>
</ul>
```